# How to match two table in mysql

Tags: mysql, matching

I want to ask if there is a "pratical" solution to match two table...

For example, I have two table, supply and demand with same columns.
For each rows in the supply table, I want to know how many demand match with these, and vice versa.

EDIT

example table sypply

```
id  Manufacturer    Cpu     Ram    Hdd
95  acer            i3      4gb    500gb
96  acer            i5      4gb    1tb
97  hp              i3      8g     500gb
98  sony            i7      4gb    500gb
99  samsung         i3      8g     750gb
```

and for table demand

```
id  customer    Cpu     Ram     Hdd
61  John        i3      8gb     500gb
62  Michael     x6      4gb     ssd
63  Kimi        i3      16gb    1tb
64  Sebastian   x4      16gb    1tb
65  Lewis       i5      16gb    500gb
```

Than i want to know customers that can be interested to the notebook id 95

John have 2 of 3 columns that match

Michael 1 of 3 columns

Kimi 1 of 3 columns

Sebastian 0 of 3 columns

Lewis 1 of 3 columns

If possible, I need also number of column that are matching because I must consider only matching over 50%

now I use AND/OR on cascade and with 15/20 variables it's not the top.

Thanks

Comment: You should read about joins in SQL. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and desired results.  A SQL Fiddle can also help communicate what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to attempt an answer, but it's a very vast question, especially if you want to consider performances (if both tables are big, you'll need a different solution altogether).

Assuming both tables have a small(ish) number of rows, there are at least two approaches, whether you will query more often, or insert/update supply/demands more often.

Let's say the supply/demand don't change very often, but you query it many times. One way of doing this would be to create a table, (e.g. `supply_demand_match`) with 3 fields : (`supply_id`, `demand_id`) as a PK and `score`. Score would be 0, 1, 2 or 3, based on your example, or a percentage (number of fields in common). This way you can easily and quickly query this table. For example to find what customers are interested in notebook id 95 : `select demand_id from supply_demand_match where supply_id = 95 and score > 1`(or 2, or 50%, or whatever you decided to go for the score).

Now how to fill this table? Every time you insert/update a new supply or a new demand, you will need to insert/update all corresponding rows. You could do it with a script in whatever scripting language you are using, or in pure SQL (possibly with a trigger if you feel like it). For example something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO supply_demand_match (supply_id, demand_id, score) (
   SELECT supply.id, demand.id,
   IF(supply.Cpu = demand.Cpu, 1, 0) + IF (supply.Ram = demand.Ram,1,0) + ... as score
   FROM supply
   JOIN demand
   WHERE ...
)
```

Note that the join has no join condition, so every rows combination will be processed by MySQL to calculate every possible scores. It can take quite a while!

Now if you insert/update more often than you will query the results, you do not need to store the results in a table, that would be counter-productive. You can combine the above `SELECT` query with a `HAVING` clause, such as `HAVING score >= 2`